# Wordpress: Show menu only on specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I want to make a menu visible only on a specific page -> "Portfolio", and when browsing on other pages the "Primary" menu should be visible. On the "Portfolio"-page the "Primary"-menu should be hidden.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work: It gives me a HTTP ERROR 500.

```
<?php if ( is_page('Portfolio') ) : ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'portfolio', 'menu_id' => 'portfolio-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php
global $post;
$post_title = isset($post->post_title) ? $post->post_title : null;
?>

<?php if ( $post_title == 'Portfolio') : ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'portfolio', 'menu_id' => 'portfolio-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
<?php else : ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I think it's better to make the IF like this: `<?php if(! is_page_template('content-portfolio-toolkit.php') ) : ?> `. When doing this, the "Portfolio"-menu is visible on **all** pages, but the "Primary"-menu is hidden. Still doesn't work as it should tho.

Comment: Are you sure both menus exist - if you just output the primary-menu it displays as it should? That code works fine for me (when using two of my own menus)

Comment: It seems like Wordpress didn't know the Portfolio-title by any reason. I got it work by change the slug to 'portfolio-test' and then do an IF: (is_page( 'portfolio-test' )). This works. Thanks for your time, Simon.

Comment: Glad to hear is @Musa :) the slug is a bit safer as well in case anyone changes the title - you have to manually update the slug else it just stays as it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an "ELSE" then Remove the

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: When removing the <?php endif; ?> before the "ELSE" only the "Primary"-menu is visible on all pages. The "Portfolio"-menu is not visible. Thanks.